Media query error code: { expectedcss(css-lcurlyexpected)
I have run into an error code regarding my media query. It is coming up with 3 error codes for an expected curly bracket. Specifically on the '@media' and its closing '}' and the the closing '}' for 'html, body'. I have this css set up in another file and there isn't an error code. I'm not really sure how to move forward and fix this. (Please see screenshots attached to see the errors. I've had a look at adding the missing space after h1{ + a{ but that isn't coming up as an issue.)
Error code:
{ expectedcss(css-lcurlyexpected)
Media query:
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    html, body {
        --border-radius: 50px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 200px;
    }
    
    h2 {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    a {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    section.vscroll {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    section.vscroll figure {
        flex-basis: 25vh;
    }
    
    section.vscroll figure img {
        width: 20%;
    }
    
    footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: stretch;
    }
        
    footer .SCL-info .copyright {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

[Code error screenshots](https://i.sstatic.net/trbs91Zy.png)

What's giving you the error?

There doesn't appear to be an error in the code you have given so at the moment we probably can't help you. Is there any surrounding code we should see? And what checking service is giving you this error?

The @media + it's closing } and then the closing } for html, body.
I'm using VSCode where it shows up as an error.

What html, body? Can you add that?

The one referenced in the css above. Everything else in the style sheet seems okay.

But that has a cloaing bracket so why another one?

Honestly I don't know, as it seems to me that there are the right amount of closing brackets, and no missing ones. Which is why I'm not sure what I am missing in terms of the errors. Unless its a VSCode bug...?

Looks ok to me, this may be throwing it:
 --border-radius: 50px;

Doesn't render for me because I'm not calling a variable
var( --border-radius);

But that should not matter. Copy the code into another editor or run in another browser. Good luck!

Thanks! I removed that but still seems to be an error within the editor. I've inspected it in browser and it isn't coming up with an error so must be the editor...

Thanks for all the help and suggestions everyone.

Yep, sounds like the editor. Good luck!
